# Showing $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>b]=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(X>b)}\int_b^{\infty}xf(x)dx$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a continous random variable with pdf $f$ and let $b$ be a
>   real number. Show that
>   $$\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>b]=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(X>b)}\int_b^{\infty}xf(x)dx.\tag1$$

I do not know the type of distribution of $X$ but the range is $[b,\infty)$. According to definition we have that:

> Let $X$ be a continous random variable and $B$ and event with
>   $\mathbb{P}(B)>0.$ The *conditional expectation* of $X$ given $B$ is
>   defined as   $$\mathbb{E}[X \mid B]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x \mid B) \ dx.\tag2$$

In my case, $B=X>b$. Substituting into $(2)$ gives

$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>b]=\int_{b}^{\infty}xf_X(x \mid X>b) \ dx.$$

I do not get anywhere from here.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Because$$
P(X \leqslant x \mid X > b) = \frac{P(b < X \leqslant x)}{P(X > b)} = \frac{1}{P(X > b)} \int_b^x f_X(y) \,\d y, \quad \forall x > b
$$
then$$
f_X(x \mid X > b) = \frac{f_X(x)}{P(X > b)}. \quad \forall x > b
$$

Comment: But I have $P(X|X>b),$ not $P(X|\le x|X> b)$. Is $x=\infty$ in my case? I also don't understand how you got to the second line from the first. It seems like you're saying that $P(X\le x|X>b)=f_X(x|X>b).$ How come?

Comment: @Parseval First, the conditional distribution function should be written as $P(X\leqslant x\mid X>b)$ instead of $P(X\mid X>b)$ because “$X$” is not an event. The second line is because if$$P(X\leqslant x\mid X>b)=\int_b^x g(y)\,\mathrm dy\quad(\forall y>b)$$for some integrable $g$, then $f_X(x\mid X>b)=g(x)$.

Comment: So $f(x)=P(X\le x|X>b)$. I'm sorry I don't understand, I feel like you're just throwing around different notations here and there. Don't misunderstand me, I don't doubt the correctness of your math, it's just I who cant follow.  Am I even correct till my last step? I assume you're showing me how to find $f_X(x|X>b)$ so that I can plug it into my answer?

Comment: @Parseval $f_X(x\mid X>b)$ is **not** $P(X\leqslant x\mid X>b)$ but $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(P(X\leqslant x\mid X>b))$. Also, your last step is correct since it's the definition of conditional expectation.